# Fill lookup on task with ID from 'Related to' Object in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

When a new Task is inserted(before insert) I want to get a lookup field from the object in it's 'whatId'(related to) and assign that to a lookup on the task. This is what I have, I'm pretty sure there is no danger of the 'whatId' being blank so don't worry about that:

```
    List<Id> pmgIds = new List<Id>();
    for(SObject temprecord : Trigger.New){
        pmgIds.add(temprecord.get('WhatId'));
    }

    for(Practice_Management_Guide__c pmg : [SELECT Id,Name,Client__c 
                                            FROM Practice_Management_Guide
                                            WHERE Id IN :pmgIds]){
        for(SObject temprecord:Trigger.New){
            if(temprecord.get('WhatId') == pmg.Id){
                temprecord.Client__c = pmg.Client__c;
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm curious is there a better way to do this ? Am I right in saying that you have to query to get other fields from an object related by 'WhatId' ?

Comment: WhatId can be null, but it would be ignored by the query anyways (it's only interested in values that are actually possible). You're right in presuming that you don't need to check for null in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right in saying that you have to query to get other fields from an object related by 'WhatId' ?

Yes, you're entirely right. The only exceptions are a handful of core fields (`Type` and `Name`, off the top of my head) that you can access directly by querying through the `What` relationship.

As with any cross-relationship fields, you do have to query to obtain data from another object within your trigger. The trick with `WhoId` and `WhatId` (and `OwnerId`) is that the lookups are polymorphic, so you cannot query from the trigger through the relationship. Instead, you have to accumulate the Ids as you do here and write a separate query against a specific parent object.

> I'm curious is there a better way to do this ?

There are some changes you need to make in your code. In particular, this double-loop structure is one of the least efficient ways to search.

Instead, do

```
Map<Id, Practice_Management_Guide__c> pmgMap = new Map<Id, Practice_Management_Guide__>(
    [SELECT Id,Name,Client__c FROM Practice_Management_Guide WHERE Id IN :pmgIds]
);
```

Then, when you loop back over `Trigger.new`, you can just do `pmgMap.get(thisTask.WhatId)`.

You don't need to treat `Trigger.new` as untyped sObjects. You can assign it to a list of typed objects (`List<Task>`) and refer to fields directly on your Tasks rather than using `get()`.